# Find Missing Element in XML c#

Tags: c#, xml, wpa

Is there any way to find the missing element from XML2.xml with XML1.xml

Example
XML1

```
<Student ID="1" Name="John"/>
<Student ID="2" Name="Antony"/>
<Student ID="3" Name="Chris"/>
```

XML2

```
<Student ID="1" Name="John"/>
<Student ID="3" Name="Chris"/>
```

OUTPUT

Student ID = "2" Name="Antony" is missing something like other..

Actually I was comparing two XML Files but it shows the Difference but it always ignores the missing one or the new one which need to update on client xml.

Hope this info will help :)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have these two documents:

```xml
<document>
  <Student ID="1" Name="John"/>
  <Student ID="2" Name="Antony"/>
  <Student ID="3" Name="Chris"/>
</document>
```

AND

```xml
<document>
  <Student ID="1" Name="John"/>
  <Student ID="3" Name="Chris"/>
</document>
```

You can use something like this:

```cs
public static void ReadXml()
{
    var doc1Students = GetStudents(XDocument.Load("your/path1")).ToList();
    var doc2Students = GetStudents(XDocument.Load("your/path2")).ToHashSet();
    foreach (var (id, name) in doc1Students)
    {
        if (!doc2Students.Contains((id, name)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Student ID = \"{id}\" Name=\"{name}\" is missing");
        }
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<(string Id, string Name)> GetStudents(XContainer doc)
{
    return doc.Descendants("Student")
        .Select(n => (n.Attribute("ID")?.Value, n.Attribute("Name")?.Value))
        .Where(tuple => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tuple.Item1));
}
```

Comment: This algorithm runs in `O(n^2)`. If the lists are long, storing `doc2Students` `Id`s in a `HashSet<int>` and testing with `Contains` would bring it down to `O(n)`.

Comment: Good point, I changed it to `HashSet`.

Comment: @MihailBrinza Thank you for your response after implementing it I got 2 errors (1)error CS8370: Feature 'nullable reference types' is not available in C# 7.3. Please use language version 8.0 or greater. (2)error CS8370: Feature 'not pattern' is not available in C# 7.3. Please use language version 9.0 or greater.

Comment: Only the second list must be in a hashset, because the first one is iterated. A hashset is not ideal for iteration.

Comment: @GøúthãmÑåîdü I edited the response, i was using `id is not null`, and the `is not` operation only became available in c# 8, it should work now.

Comment: It worked. I marked as Answer, Anyway nice to meet you @MihailBrinza Thank for your time :)

Comment: Best way is to use a Left Outer Join [DefaultIfEmpty()].  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins